# Dwarf Fortress Monarchy

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my fort in *Dwarf Fortress* a fire breathing Forgotten Beast attacked and killed my king. I am still listed as a Mountainhome yet there is no monarch in the nobles screen. Even weirder, the queen consort become the Sheriff *even though I already have a Captain of the Guard!* She also has the room requirements but the room requirements of a sheriff not a queen. She is also not listed on the nobles screen. Please tell me what is happening and how to get another monarch.

Comment: AFAIK, the crown would get inherited by the next in line... at least that's what happens during worldgen. The queen consort is not in line, just as with real-life monarchies. Did the couple produce any children (can check the queen's relations screen). Does the king have living brothers/sisters?